# Xamarin.Forms ImageButton Display Issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use an ImageButton in a StackLayout and attempting to set the text of the button to be set below the image. However, the text is always displayed on the right side of the image instead of below. here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout x:Class="MyApp.Portable.Controls.MyNavigationControl"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Libraries.PCL"
             x:Name="MyNavControl"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             MinimumHeightRequest="75"
             Orientation="Horizontal">
  <StackLayout.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="NavButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="7" />
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </StackLayout.Resources>
  <forms:ImageButton x:Name="GpsButton"
                        Clicked="GpsBUttonClicked"
                        Image="GPS_Icon_Light_Gray_sm.png"
                        MinimumHeightRequest="75"
                        Orientation="ImageOnBottom"
                        Style="{StaticResource NavButtonStyle}"
                        Text="GPS"
                        VerticalOptions="Start" />
<StackLayout>
```

Comment: If you want the text below the image, shouldn't you use "ImageOnTop" orientation?

Comment: That was left over from testing...  both bottom or top settings result in text on right

Comment: is your button tall enough to fix the image and text?

Comment: I believe so: MinimumHeightRequest="75"...  when looking at the control the stacklayout is filled about halfway by the image.

Comment: You might try bumping it up - a lot - just to be sure that lack of space isn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found it yet, here is the answer to your question. The problem is a matter of using the incorrect property to set the Image. The `ImageButton.Image` property will display the image however it will not adhere to any other set properties such as `ImageButton.Orientation`. To solve your issue you must set the `ImageButton.Source` property instead.

More info can be found here: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/235